# Breaking a looping integral $\int\frac1x\ln(\frac1{x^2+1})dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Said integral being $$\int\frac1x\ln(\frac1{x^2+1})dx$$ 
I've tried solving it with normal integration by parts exploiting that $$\ln(\frac1{x^2+1})=(-1)\ln(x^2+1)$$ but no dice. I'm trying to find a way to shoehorn in $arctanx$ as a primitive of $\frac1{x^2+1}$ without making the rest unreasonably complicated.

Comment: Do you expect to find a closed-form, elementary anti-derivative?

Comment: I'm actually just supposed to find the definite integral for 1<x<2. I tried to pose y=(starting integral) and find it indirectly but it just loops on itself with no usable coefficents.

Comment: It's always useful to add this information and/or relevant context; sometimes you can find a definite integral without explicitly finding an anti-derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**
$$\ln\left(\frac1{x^2+1}\right) = -\ln \left(x^2+1\right)$$
$$-\int\frac{\ln \left(x^2+1\right)}{x}dx$$
Set $$u = -x^2 \implies dx = -\frac{1}{2x}\,du$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\ln\left(1-u\right)}{u}du$$

Comment: I've tried to put the -1/2 aside and resolve the new integral by parts but I'm still stumped.

Comment: it's because it's not a standard integral.See:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm